# How to view the disassembly in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, codeblocks, low-level

I read [this article](http://altdevblogaday.com/2011/11/09/a-low-level-curriculum-for-c-and-c/) about some low level underpinnings of C/C++, and the author is basically showing us through the assembly code generated by the compiler, line by line. He is using VS 2010, but I don't, I use Code::Blocks. How do I view the disassembly there? When I go to debugger, and click disassembly, it shows me a blank window...

This is the C++ (.cpp) code (the whole code) I compiled:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    int z = 0;

    z = x + y;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are just interested in assembly and not Code Blocks in particular you can use `gcc -S` and it'll generate an assembly file on the lines of *.s, *.asm

Comment: Cool, I'll boot Linux and do that. But I'd like to know how to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The kind of disassembly that the author shows in the article is called `inter-leaved disassembly` ( C and disassembly interleaved ) which a few IDEs like Visual Studio support. Code Blocks does not support. But Code Blocks has a separate disassembly window like this

[image: Diassembly Window]

Select a source line. Right Click. Say `Run to Cursor`. Now `Debug->Debugging Windows->Disassembly`. Instead of Run to cursor you can also set break points and then do this. But somehow it wasn't going well with mine, so I am suggesting `Run to Cursor` method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: OK. Lets sync up from the beginning. I dwlded Code Blocks from here- http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/10.05/Windows/codeblocks-10.05mingw-setup.exe/download
`File->New->Project->Console Application->C++->Enter Project Title->GNU GCC Compiler->Finish`
Now, `Build->Build`. Now place the cursor @ line 7 in `main.cpp`. Right Click and say `Run to Cursor`. Now a pop up window asks whether you wanna save perspective. Say no! Now, do as explained in the answer

Comment: @Bane Any luck with my latest comment?

Comment: Sorry for the wait, but I have been occupied by something else. I did what you said, I can now see the `Run to cursor` command. When I execute it, something starts happening, a console window pops up for a moment, but there is no window that asks me something about the perspective. After that, I opened up the disassembly, and this is what I saw: http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/1395/tse.png.
I didn't download the same version as you did, but I think that things like this shouldn't be different. I am downloading the new version now to make sure, though.

Comment: "Installer integrity check has failed", an error of that kind appears. I think I have the newest Code::Blocks version, and I doubt that they would change such a feature...

Comment: Are the breakpoints hitting? When the breakpoint hits, Disassembly window should automatically be populated

Comment: Seems like they aren't. I've put a breakpoint (that little red dot) at line 7, I compile it, then run it, all the while having the disassembly window opened, but "nothing" happens. It just compiles and runs, doesn't indicate anything else...

Comment: I think you are _running_ it and not _debugging_ it. After setting the breakpoint ( Just say toggle breakpoint on any line, a new BP will come up ) Now select `Debug->Start` ( F8 shortcut ) **NOT** `Build->Run`. Now BPs will surely hit and you will see disassembly populated

Comment: Aha! It works now. I am at my school now, and I remember that at home, I couldn't `start` the debugger. Probably because some of the settings. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is a new answer to an old post. The other answer is completely on topic, but makes one outdated statement: *"Code Blocks* ***does not support***_",... *inter-leaved disassembly ( C and disassembly interleaved )*.

This is no longer true. Newer versions of Code::Blocks have updated that feature.

Using Code::Blocks version 17.12 with gcc (tdm-1) version 5.1.0 and the OP code

And following the instructions:

- In the `Code::Blocks` editor, right-click on the line of interest in the source file, and from the resulting context menu select `Run to cursor`. For this illustration the closing bracket `}` for the main function was right clicked.
- Then, from title bar menu select `Debug->Debugging Windows->Disassembly`.  This results in a popup showing assembly interleaved with source code:
- This results in the following image clearly showing that the C source and assembly code are interleaved:

[image]

Comment: Zombie, Zombie :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ejga4kJUts  - resuurection of an old thread reminded me of this song.